# Setting footer to ListView

Tags: android

everyone.
Can you help me with setting footer to ListView? I've described footer in layouts, and then:

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom, getListView(), false);
getListView().addFooterView(footer);
```

But it didn't appear... Can you give an example? Also I need to set the height of footer dynamically. Here is the code of footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#87ceeb"
    >
<TextView android:id="@+id/loading"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:text="Loading..."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did this help? Accept and answer if so so others know to look here.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to do dynamic footer? I didn't succeed, so I moved to static...

Comment: Dynamic? In the code exmaple, you can change the textview to a linearlayout and have anything you want down there.

Comment: I mean, hide and show. They have some restrictions like: you can set Footer only before adapter and so on...

Comment: @damlur, That is not a footer... That is just a view below your listview. Again, you can reference is in your code and change anything about it or the views inside it as you like. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with RelativeLayout.

1) Create a RelativeLayout for the whole layout.
2) Create two views, perhaps ListView and LinearLayout for the footer.
3) Make the listView aligned to the parent top with a bottom margin equal to the height of the footer view or linear layout.
4) make the linear layout aligned the parent bottom

Done. Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Some quick code to try and get the point across:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Some text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wow... didnt keep formatting. Let me know if this helps else I can post code when I get back to my computer but it really is easy.

Comment: making  android:layout_height="wrap_content" for list view is not good idea especially for large list

Answer (score 3):

There can be few reasons for this, 
Have you added your code

getListView().addFooterView(footer); before the setAdapter of ListView ? If yes.

There might be problem in xml layout, 
If your listview is wrap_content and your footerlayout has fill_parent , Footer might not appear unless some text is there in your textview of footer layout.

Change the listview layout_width="fill_parent" and footer layout's layout_width="fill_parent"

To quickly check , give a background color to your footer layout and see its placement.
Hope it helps.